# Multiple Rewrite rules not working in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my code in .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product\.php\?course_name=([^\s&]+)&course_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)([^/]+)/?$ /product.php?course_name=$1&course_id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Which is working fine but now I have to check if a user enters a wrong address in my website like www.example.com/no-file-exists.php then it will redirect to my 404page.php which I build to show an error message.
So I have this rule RewriteRule ^  404page.php and put it in my code then my previous rule will be overwritten so I don't know where to put in order to get all rules working, please help?

Comment: Show us the rule which is breaking it?

Comment: RewriteRule ^ 404page.php  that is the rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a side-note: The rule `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)([^/]+)/?$ /product.php?course_name=$1&course_id=$2 [L,QSA]` seems to be wrong. I think you forgot a `/` ;-)

You can solve your problem by not writing another rewriterule, but instead make a handler for 404 errors. You can do this with `ErrorDocument` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument)). You would end up with something like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php
```

Reminder: If the second argument (`/404page.php`) doesn't begin with a slash (`/`), then it is treated like a string of text to send with the 404 not found header. You don't want that.